# ¿Por qué se recarga el html con javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Cada vez que presiono el botón para insertar algo en una tabla que lo hago por *javascript* y *jquery,* siempre me recarga la página y no se por qué pasa.

Tengo este **código en javascript:**

```
function insertarTabla(size) {
var row = $('<tr>');
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    row.append($('<td>').html("HOLA Q TAL :v"));
    row.append($('<td>').html("HOLA Q TAL :v"));
    row.append($('<td>').html("HOLA Q TAL :v"));
    row.append($('<td>').html("HOLA Q TAL :v"));
}
$('#myTable').append(row);}
```

y este en **html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='./js/jquery-3.2.1.js'></script>
    <script id='protec' type='text/javascript' src='./js/menuscript.js'></script>
    <style>
        table, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="" class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                <label for="fechaIn">Fecha de inicio:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="fechaIn" type="date">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                <label for="fechaFin">Fecha de inicio:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="fechaFin" type="date">
            </div>
            <button onclick="insertarTabla(1)" class="btn btn-primary" id='send'>Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Numero Transaccion</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Sede</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Descripcion Procedimiento</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Estado</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Prueba sacando el botón del formulario.

Comment: puedes añadir `onsubmit="return false"` ejemplo `<form onsubmit="return false">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/button#Atributos) por defecto de los `button` es `submit`.

Asignale un `type="button"` y listo.

El código:

```js
function insertarTabla(size) {
var row = $('<tr>');
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    row.append($('<td>').html("HOLA Q TAL :v"));
    row.append($('<td>').html("HOLA Q TAL :v"));
    row.append($('<td>').html("HOLA Q TAL :v"));
    row.append($('<td>').html("HOLA Q TAL :v"));
}
$('#myTable').append(row);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        table, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    
    <div class="container">
        <form action="" class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                <label for="fechaIn">Fecha de inicio:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="fechaIn" type="date">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                <label for="fechaFin">Fecha de inicio:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="fechaFin" type="date">
            </div>
            <button onclick="insertarTabla(1)" class="btn btn-primary" id='send' type="button">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Numero Transaccion</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Sede</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Descripcion Procedimiento</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Estado</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: jajaja entiendo!, gracias por la corrección!